# PHP ob_start() question

Tags: php, output-buffering

Am I allowed to have two or more `ob_start();` in my php files if so what is the proper way to end one `ob_start();` and start another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual:

> Output buffers are stackable, that is,
>   you may call ob_start() while another
>   ob_start() is active. Just make sure
>   that you call ob_end_flush() the
>   appropriate number of times. If
>   multiple output callback functions are
>   active, output is being filtered
>   sequentially through each of them in
>   nesting order.

In addition to stacking (nesting), you can have separate blocks in sequence.

```
<?
ob_start();
echo "Foo";
ob_end_flush(); // outputs buffer contents and turns off output buffering

ob_start();
echo "Bar";
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to do more than one ob_start() on a page. You end ob_start() with ob_end_clean().

```
ob_start();
$postOutput = preg_replace('/<img[^>]+./','', ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
echo $postOutput;
```

Comment: If you're not doing any additional processing of `$postOutput` then `ob_end_clean()` just makes extra work compared to `ob_end_flush()`

Comment: Right, since ob_end_clean is going to erase the top buffer.